# How to publish a website over command line from asp dot net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have inherited a asp.net project that i'm trying to incorporate into our continuous integration tool.  I've successfully got other C# web applications to compile via msbuild and into the CI, but this project seems different.  It has no .csproj / .sln / .vsproj to open, and I open the project in visual studio 2012 via "Open Web Site"

Normally, the dev's will just run "Publish Web Site" via visual studio, and this is the process that I want to run over command line so that I can get it into our CI.

A lot of SO answers involve the .sln or .csproj file which I don't have, and also a publishing profile, which I don't have.

Any ideas or solutions on how I can get this project to publish via command line?

Comment: Is it an asp project (makes me assume classic asp) like in the problem description, or an asp.net project as indicated by the tag?

Comment: asp.net , will modify and try to make it more clear, sorry!

Comment: Then it sounds like an old school web site project. These were how the first couple versions of Visual Studio organized web development. Newer versions will allow you to open them, but are limited on what they will support doing with them. My advice would be: If you have the resources and time redesign/rewrite it using modern techniques. If you don't have the time or resources for a rewrite, create a new web forms application and start porting the old one over a bit at a time until you have it all working in the new application (won't save a lot of time compared to a rewrite, but some).

Comment: Thanks Kevin!  I'm not a .net developer by trade, but if I get this old web site project updated, does that mean i'll have an actual project file create that can be used to publish over the command line via msbuild or msdeploy?

Comment: Yes if you port it to a Web Forms project you'll have everything you need.